# Js barcode reader

Tags: javascript, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have barcode image:

[image]

And I need to read this barcode.
I tried use getBarcodeFromImage() function from [this](http://tobeytailor.s3.amazonaws.com/get_barcode_from_image/index.html) example.

```
<img src="photo.jpg" id="barcode" >
<button onclick="alert(getBarcodeFromImage('barcode'))">Scan</button>
```

But I get this code: 18XXXXX21XXX

I think it is wrong.

How can I solve this problem and read barcode?

Thanks.

Comment: The function in your site doesn't work properly. Because the same barcode pic gives correct output (i.e. the same numbers as printed on bottom) on this site: http://www.onlinebarcodereader.com/

Comment: Your question appears to essentially boil down to "This library doesn't work with my data". There are three things you can do. (1) Find a different library (product recommendation questions are off-topic). (2) File a support request with whomever maintains the library (not a problem for Stackoverflow). (3) Try to fix the problem yourself (in which case you need to make an attempt — *this means editing the source code of the library* — and then provide an [mcve]) in the question).

Comment: Thanks for comment. Yes, I see that this library doesn't work, so I need other library for it.

Comment: @NastyaGorobets — As I said "product recommendation questions are off-topic"

Answer (score 1):

The barcode you are trying to scan is of type Code 128C. Tobias' program only works on UPC symbols.